# Handling click on 3d object opengl

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

i've started my second project targeted for graphical representation of current network and already done the backend. Now i'm building UI with opengl and faced the problem that i need to handle click on 3d object

```
GLUquadricObj * gluObj = gluNewQuadric();
glPushName(PLUTO);
glTranslated(x / 100.0, y / 100.0, z / 100.0);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, texture[0]);
gluQuadricTexture(gluObj, true);
gluSphere(gluObj, radius / 100.0, 100, 100);
gluDeleteQuadric(gluObj);
```

how can i handle click on sphere and perform some action after click?

Answer (score 0):

The technique used to map mouse click to open GL object is called picking.

following article explain one such picking technique.
http://www.codeguru.com/Cpp/G-M/opengl/article.php/c5579

[here](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/3097/Mouse-Selection-in-OpenGL-Scene) is another link.

Comment: that are usefull links but i can't use WIN API , i'm only allowed for qt and pure c++

Comment: ahh, i think you will get working sample for Qt if you search for keyword "color picking" or just picking for OpenGL.

Comment: Do you mean that i can pick color from current position of cursor? That's good idea, but i think this solution will produce more comlex solution when identifing specific object in space, i mean that there will be a lots of 3d objects and i'm searching for solution where i can give id for each object and set onclick listener for each object  or something like that. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @user1280078: OpenGL has no idea of geometrical "objects" all it sees are points, lines and triangles drawn. (There used to be the selection feedback system, but I strongly discourage its use -- doing it will make your program sloooow). Since OpenGL has no idea about individual objects, you'll have to somehow implement a way to identify objects on the screen. Either by ray picking into a structure you maintain. Or by rendering each object with a unique ID color into a ID framebuffer.

Comment: Ok i've got it. What you mean under unique ID color? Do i need to give different colors to each 3d object? Or i've missed some specifics about this stuff?

Comment: -1 Link-only answers are discouraged. Please consider adding more details, explaination or code examples to improve the quality of your answer.